# Retrieve build in Event Hub-compatible endpoint with PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-iot-hub

I would like to obtain the endpoint string relating to the hub IoT "EventHub compatible endpoint" that is the one that begins with `Endpoint = sb // ....` which is found in the hub in the built-in endpoint.
By creating the endpoint on Azure, the system communicates

> Each IoT hub comes with built-in system endpoints to handle system and
> device messages. When you create new endpoints and routes, messages
> stop flowing to the built-in endpoint unless you create a separate
> route and direct them there.

I have not created any routing endpoints so the command

```
Get-AzIotHubRoutingEndpoint -ResourceGroupName <r_name> -Name <iothubname> -EndpointType EventHub
```

which should return the endpoint, does not return anything, but it is the only command I have found that gave me a minimum of "hope of find it".

Thank you in advance
Amf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, it looks like a bug, from the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.iothub/get-aziothubroutingendpoint?view=azps-5.4.0#example-3) in the doc, the command you used is the correct way.

If you want to get the `Event Hub-compatible endpoint` like in the portal, you could use the workaround below, in my sample, it uses the `iothubowner` shared access policy by default, you can also use others e.g. `service`, `$endpoint` is what you want.

```
$groupname = "<groupname>"
$iothubname = "<iothubname>"
$sapolicy = "iothubowner"
$a = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $groupname -ResourceType Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs -Name $iothubname).Properties.eventHubEndpoints.events.endpoint
$key = (Get-AzIotHubKey -ResourceGroupName $groupname -Name $iothubname -KeyName $sapolicy).PrimaryKey
$endpoint = "Endpoint="+ $a + ";SharedAccessKeyName="+ $sapolicy +";SharedAccessKey=" + $key + ";EntityPath=" + $iothubname
```

[image]

Comment: Almost perfect :-) IoT Hub truncates the Event Hub-compatible name to 25 characters. So i ended up with replacing the last line with: 

$endpoint = "Endpoint="+ $a + ";SharedAccessKeyName="+ $sapolicy +";SharedAccessKey=" + $key + ";EntityPath=" + $iothubname.substring(0,25)